# Check if two dates are identical, if yes, insert value in adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying my best to get this to work, but to no avail. As the image shows, columns F and P have dates. If the dates match, the corresponding value from column Q (close) has to be inserted into column H next to the correct date from F.
E.g. Q2 --> h2, Q5 --> H7.

[image: Example]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does the `IF` function work for you? `=If(A1=B1; C1; "")`? . See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Why are you using an image, if you can provide the same data as text?

Answer (score 2):

To see if the date1 is in the list of date2 use

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,B:C,2,FALSE),"")
```

or from your original image use in column H:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F:F,P:Q,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: @NicolasRosenthal Which error? where? This works I tested it. What exactly have you done? • Depending on your excel version you might need to use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: How do I do that? Also, (and sorry for another question) what formula would I use to assign the "count" value with the same date from column G to the dates from column P into a new column R?

Comment: @NicolasRosenthal come on, that is an easy transfer and almost the same formula give it a try, you just need to adjust the columns in the lookup (If you don't get it to work show what you have tried). And I gave you a link in my last comment that shows exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula - use it in 'Target' column.

```
=IF(A2=B2,C2,"")
```

Comment: the issue is that the left date column has all dates but the one on the right is missing the weekends (stock prices) so it only works until the first weekend

Comment: @NicolasRosenthal: can you give an example of what works and what not? (How do the dates look like) Please modify the original question.

Comment: i originally had an image inserted, which was now removed, let me see what i can do - added the image in the original post